# How To check Windows device is rooted/jailbrake or not programatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, jailbreak, rooted-device

Since I am new to Windows Phone Technology, I want to programatically find in my application that windows device is rooted/jailbrake or not. I found many links but it seems like no way for finding rooted windows device programatically. So is there any way to find rooted/jailbreak windows device programatically any API available for this ? Can anyone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: There is not really any such thing as 'jailbreaking' or 'rooting' a Windows Phone. There is 'developer unlock', but I don't believe there is any way to check that status programatically.

Comment: @pumpkinszwan [You are not right](https://www.google.com/search?q=root+windows+phone+7). You can root WP7 device and get access to the registry and other system components. Root status can be checked by accessing these components(registry, for example). But you'll fail certification in store (I think).

Comment: @crea7or, as far as I know, in order to access filesystem or registry you need ID_CAP_INTEROPSERVICES capability, which will not only fail certification in the store but wouldn't even allow you to install application on a regular device without interop-unlock.

Answer (score 7):

Rooting and/or jailbreaking is not officially supported by Microsoft and therefore there is no official way for you to check if your application is running on such device.

In principle, you could check that, but that check would involve adding stuff to your application that would not pass the certification which means that you can run *that* application *only* on jailbroken device.

Which then means that you don't need to check at all since you already know that you are running on such hardware.